# Intersection of two-dimensional lists in one axis

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I've these two lists:

```
l1 = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}, {d, 4}};
l2 = {{b, 5}, {d, 6}, {f, 7}};
```

Every list element is a two-coordinates point. I want to retrieve elements of both lists that have the first coordinate in common with the other list.

In the example we can see that the lists have in common the `b` and `d` first element coordinate. I can find it with following command:

```
commonIndices = Intersection[l1[[;; , 1]], l2[[;; , 1]]]
```

It returns `{b, d}`. What I want to do now is to elaborate this result in order to obtain these lists:

```
ll1 = {{b, 2}, {d, 4}};
ll2 = {{b, 5}, {d, 6}};
```

that are the sublists of `l1` and `l2` that have as first coordinate one of the indices found with previous command.

Ho can I obtain this result?

Comment: I think you should wait a bit longer before accepting an answer, next time. I also don't mind if you decide to redistribute  the acception, e.g. to aardvark2012's answer. It is definately much faster than mine for large lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ll1 = Select[l1, MemberQ[commonIndices, #[[1]]] &]
ll2 = Select[l2, MemberQ[commonIndices, #[[1]]] &]
```

> {{b, 2}, {d, 4}}
>
> {{b, 5}, {d, 6}}

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

You can get the result as an `Association` with

```
KeyIntersection[AssociationThread @@ Transpose[#] & /@ {l1, l2}]

(* {<|b -> 2, d -> 4|>, <|b -> 5, d -> 6|>} *)
```

If you want it as a list:

```
{ll1, ll2} = % /. Association | Rule -> List

(* {{{b, 2}, {d, 4}}, {{b, 5}, {d, 6}}} *)
```

Comment: That's a great one. You can speed it up even more by using `AssociationThread`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Awesome. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to use `commonIndices`:

```
ll1=Intersection[l1, l2, SameTest -> (First[#1] === First[#2] &)]
ll2=Intersection[l2, l1, SameTest -> (First[#1] === First[#2] &)]
```

Comment: Note that the essential part of the intersection gets computed twice this way.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher That's true.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = Cases[{Alternatives @@ #2[[All, 1]], _}] @ # &;

f[l1, l2]
```

> ```
> {{b, 2}, {d, 4}}
> ```

```
f[l2, l1]
```

> ```
> {{b, 5}, {d, 6}}
> ```